# Selenium Doc - How to use?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using the following selenium doc ( http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html ),However not sure how can I use it effectively. for example: if I have to use Class Keyboard and method pressKeys(), then as per this document which class should I import to use the pressKeys() method. Here is my code but it is not working

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement; 
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Keyboard;

public class myclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\selenium-java-2.35.0\\chromedriver_win32_2.2\\chromedriver.exe");        
         WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 

 //Open gmail
         driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");


driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).pressKeys

}

}
```

Error msg I'm getting for the last line is : "pressKeys cannot be resolved or is not a field"

What Am I missing here? Is it the import class? if yes, how can I find the class from the above doc everytime I use a new class or method?

Answer (score 2):

pressKeys is not a function I have ever seen.

If you want to click on it, do:

```
.click();
```

If you want to type something, do:

```
.sendKeys("thing to type");
```

If you want to type a special character, do:

```
.sendKeys(Keys.Return);
```

Comment: if pressKeys is not a method then what are these similar api's http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html

Comment: pressKey is a function provided by the java Keyboard class.  Selenium uses it internally...but its not for people that use Selenium.  Use sendKeys.  If you want to use pressKey, then instantiate Keyboard yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you have to fix:

1. **The reason you are getting this error** is because you did not put parentheses with a CharSequence argument after the method, and so the compiler thinks it is a field.

2. **Even if you add parentheses** with a CharSequence argument, `pressKeys()` is not a method that you can call off of a WebElement.  You would have to call it off of a Keyboard, except:

3. **The spelling of the method has a typo**.  There is no `pressKeys()`.  What you want is either `pressKey()` or `sendKeys()` (I would recommend `sendKeys()`).

4. Finally, **you don't need to use a Keyboard object** to use `sendKeys()`, as you can call it right off of a WebElement (unlike `pressKey()`).

So, I recommend doing this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("Type whatever you want here");
```

If you want to use `pressKey()` instead, you would need to instantiate an implementation of Keyboard (since Keyboard is an Interface), and then call `pressKey()` off of your Keyboard:

```
Keyboard keyboard = //instantiate implementation here
driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).click();
keyboard.pressKey("Type whatever you want here");
```

Though I'd really recommend the first solution.  It's a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpfull if you you have written down which version of Selenium are you using. However, `WebElement` have methods only for text text manipulation and getting values of attributes. So you need to use `Actions` class like

```
new Actions(driver).keyDown(driver.findElement(By.id("Email")), Keys.ENTER)
    .build().perform();
```

Comment: My question was how to use pressKeys(). I'm still not sure how to use pressKeys() using above example given by you.

Comment: @min2bro, you want `.sendKeys`. Not `.pressKeys`.